# webscalesql vs mysql. Which to use?

Tags: mysql, webscalesql

I am confused on what the difference is between webscalesql and mysql. From my understanding webscalesql is a branch of mysql. Does this mean that webscalesql is a subset of mysql, so it is better to download MySQL rather than webscalesql as the changes made in webscalesql will be merged? If so, why would anyone download webscalesql?

Comment: Flagging as Off Topic for being a shopping list question.

Comment: I am unsure how this is a shopping list question? I am simply asking about the differences and when to use which. I don't think this is an open-ended question or a question which can be outdated quickly.

Comment: "questions about which tool, library, product or resource you should use are off-topic here... If you have an issue with or a question about a specific tool, please revise your question to conform to that scope."

Comment: I think that reading this [page](http://webscalesql.org/) and this [one](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/) should tell you all you need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webscalesql is a project born in order for those organizations that maintain their own MySQL patches to use, and review each other's code. So engineers from facebook can improve twitter patches can improve Google patches and so on. It is necessary for now at least, because its seemingly difficult for Oracle to accept, QA, test and ship external code. Note the use of "seemingly". Some would argue it is not. Webscalesql is not supported by anyone so I would advise against running it in production environments without your own MySQL engineering team. Oracle, Percona and MariaDB should be the direction to look to for an implementation.

Comment: Which major company use Percona?

Comment: Not sure about Linkedin/Twitter/Facebook, but Google seems to have sent its team over to MariaDB. [Alibaba too](http://www.sohu.com/a/201807707_485557).

Answer (score 1):

webscale (https://github.com/webscalesql/webscalesql-5.6) is a fork of mysql implementing, apparently, facebook's mysql patches. These same patches are slowly making into many of the mysql forks out there.

Comment: According to webscalesql's FAQ they are branch: http://webscalesql.org/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner, simply use MySQL.  Once you have a better feel for the product, and (perhaps) your dataset grows to Facebook-size, *then* consider the various other products that help with serious scaling.

99% of users never need to go beyond the basic MySQL (Community MySQL, MariaDB, Percona's MySQL).